# simple tween is not working to move object X

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

My code below is showing two scenes side-by-side. It's working fine the way I need.

So I'm trying to simply move them using Tween and it's not working.

Am I doing something wrong?

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

//---------------------------------------

class BaseClass extends Phaser.Scene  {
  constructor(key){
    super(key);
  }

  create(data){
    this.parent = data;
    this.cameras.main.setViewport(data.x, data.y, data.width, data.height);
  }

  refresh() {
    this.cameras.main.setPosition(this.parent.x, this.parent.y);
  }
}

//---------------------------------------

class Scene1 extends BaseClass {
  constructor(){
    super('scene1');
  }

  create(data){
    super.create(data);
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'Scene1').setOrigin(0).setDepth(100);
    this.add.rectangle(0, 0, this.parent.width, this.parent.height, 0xffff00).setOrigin(0);
  }
}

//---------------------------------------

class Scene2 extends BaseClass {
  constructor(){
    super('scene2')
  }

  create(data){
    super.create(data);
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'Scene2').setOrigin(0).setDepth(100);
    this.add.rectangle(0, 0, this.parent.width, this.parent.height, 0x555555).setOrigin(0);
  }
}

//---------------------------------------

class Main extends Phaser.Scene {

  zone1;
  zone2;

  constructor(){
    super('main')
  }

  create(){

    this.openScenes();

    // click to move all
    this.label = this.add.text(10, 10, 'MOVE ALL').setOrigin(0).setDepth(110).setInteractive();
    this.label.on('pointerdown', function () {
      console.log('MOVE ALL');
      this.tweens.add({
        targets    :zone1,
        x          :{from:0, to:100},
        duration   :1000,
        onComplete :function(){ console.log('onComplete'); }
      });
    });

  }

  openScenes(){
    let layout = ['scene1', 'scene2'];
    let roomWidth = config.width/2;
    let roomHeight = config.height/2;
    for (let idx = 0; idx < layout.length; idx++){
      let room = this.add.zone(idx * roomWidth, 50, roomWidth, roomHeight).setOrigin(0);
      this.scene.run(layout[idx], room);
      this['zone'+(idx+1)] = room;
    }
  }
}

//---------------------------------------

var config = {
  type   :Phaser.AUTO,
  width  :536,
  height :183,
  scene  :[Main, Scene1, Scene2],
  banner :false
};

new Phaser.Game(config);
console.clear();
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? Did you have time to verify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue, is that you have to pass the context to the event listener, and than it should work.

```
this.label.on('pointerdown', function () {
    this.tweens.add({
        targets    :zone1,
        x          :{from:0, to:100},
        duration   :1000,
        onComplete :function(){ console.log('onComplete'); }
    });
}, this);  // <-- add 'this' here
```

And also you need to add the `this` keyword to the tween, since it is a property:

```
  this.tweens.add({
      targets    : this.zone1, //  <-- here this is missing
      x          :{from:0, to:100},
      duration   :1000,
      onComplete :function(){ console.log('onComplete'); }
  });
```

> ***Tipp:** check the browser console for errors, if phaser works in an unexpected way.*